# Connect to yahoo with YMSGPro component

Tags: c#

Is there anybody has used YMSGPro.OCX in c# ?
How can I connect to yahoo with that ?

If not used so why do I have this error -User of unassigned local variable 'js'- ?

```
YMSGClass ys;
string username="m.moh3en1375";
string password="mypw";
string host = "a";
string port = "2800";
string amoo = "";
string hole = "";
ys.Connect(ref username,ref password,ref host,ref port,ref amoo,ref hole);
```

This is wrong too :

```
YMSGClass ys = new YMSGClass();
```

Comment: You need to have some way to document this API if you want help...

Comment: Here Is The Component [link](http://www.4shared.com/file/6e9vOcRX/YMSGPro.html?)

Comment: A link to download an executable component is not the same as providing the API in question...

Comment: Giving a link to the documentation for that component would be nice - asking people to download the full component is unreasonable.

Comment: Ook but can you please tell me how can I fix that problem ( which I asked ) :D Sorry my English is trrible and I don't know what I am saying :((

Answer (score 0):

What you need is this.
https://github.com/klog/ycs

I found some VB6 code regarding this OCX.. it will be quite easy to convert it to C#.
Here is some kind of Yahoo Chatroom client using this OCX

```
Private Sub Command1_Click () 
Call YMSG1.Connect (User.Text, Pass.Text) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Command2_Click () 
Call YMSG1.PckChangeStatus (TXTST.Text, False) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Command3_Click () 
Call YMSG1.PckSendTextRoom (pmtoroom.Text) 
End Sub 

Private Sub Command4_Click () 
List1.Clear 

Call YMSG1.PckJoindRoom (Toroom.Text) 


End Sub 

Private Sub Command5_Click () 
Call YMSG1.PckLeftRoom 
End Sub 


Private Sub Form_Load () 
Call YMSG1.Invisible (True) 

End Sub 

Private Sub lblst_Change () 
If lblst.Caption = "login." Then 
YMSG1.ConvertFarsi = True 
YMSG1.FilterMessage = True 
End If 
End Sub 

Private Sub mnuAbut_Click () 
abut.Show 
End Sub 

Private Sub Timer1_Timer () 
On Error GoTo Eror 
Call YMSG1.PckSendTextRoom (PM2Room.Text) 
Eror: 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingAddRequest (ByVal From As String, ByVal ToUser As String, ByVal Message As String, ByVal SenderName As Variant, ByVal SenderLastName As String, ByVal AutoAdd As Boolean) 
YMSG1.PckAcceptAdd From, ToUser 
Call YMSG1.PckSendMsg (From, txtadd.Text) 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingAppear (ByVal User As String, ByVal Status As YMSGMode_V2.StatusYID, Messege As String) 
If Status = Available Then Call YMSG1.PckSendMsg (User, txtOnline.Text) 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingCaptcha (ByVal PictureLink As String, ByVal DATA As String) 
Form2.Web.Navigate "http://captcha.chat.yahoo.com/go/captchat/?img =" & PictureLink & "&. Intl = us &. Lang = en-US" 
Form2.Show 
Timer1.Interval = "30000" 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingChatList (ByVal ChatterLst As String, ByVal Status As YMSGMode_V2.StatusRoom, ByVal DATA As String) 
If Status = Joind Then 
List1.AddItem ChatterLst 
List2.AddItem ChatterLst & "Join Room" 
Call YMSG1.PckSendMsg (ChatterLst, txtWel.Text) 


lblUser.Caption = "Users:" & List1.ListCount 
ElseIf Status = Leave Then 
List2.AddItem ChatterLst & "Left Room" 
Call YMSG1.PckSendMsg (ChatterLst, txtWel.Text) 

For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1 
If List1.List (i) = ChatterLst Then 
List1.RemoveItem i 
End If 
Next i 
lblUser.Caption = "Users:" & List1.ListCount 
ElseIf Status = RoomFull Then 
MsgBox ("Room The Full") 
End If 


End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingMessage (ByVal From As String, ByVal ToUser As String, ByVal TextMessage As String) 
Call YMSG1.PckSendMsg (From, txtrespones.Text) 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_IncomingRoomTxtMessage (ByVal FromUser As String, ByVal Msg As String, ByVal Client As String, ByVal RoomName As String, ByVal DATA As String) 
List2.AddItem FromUser & ":" & Msg 
End Sub 

Private Sub YMSG1_Status (ByVal MsgStatus As String, ByVal Status As String, ByVal Connecting As Boolean) 
lblst.Caption = MsgStatus 
End Sub
```

Here is some pictures
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer but I do not know VB6 .

Here is my code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using YMSGPro;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            YMSGClass ym = null;
            string username = "m.mohsen1375";
            string password = "pw";
            ym.Connect(ref username, ref password);
        }
    }
}
```

The Problem is that compiler needs all 6 arguments for connect method and in your codes you just interred username and password (2 arguments) .

look here is compiler's error :

No overload for method  'Connect' takes '2' arguments.

Thank you !